# @ControllerAdvice conflict with ResourceHandler : Spring 4

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-4

I am running a Spring 4 web mvc project:

Issue:
My controlleradvice for 404 exception handler is not working. However, if I comment the "addResourceHandlers" method in WebConfig class, it will work. (I can't remove that as it resolves my static resources)_

This is my web config:

```
@EnableWebMvc
@Configuration
public class WebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    /*
     * Resource handler for static resources
     */
    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(final ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/**").addResourceLocations("classpath:/static/");
    }
}
```

And this is my 404 exception handler:

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class ExceptionController {

    @ExceptionHandler(NoHandlerFoundException.class)
    public String handle404(Exception e)   {
        return "error/404";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your webapp is using `web.xml` it's very simple - just add the following (assuming usage of *InternalResourceViewResolver* with prefix pointing at your *WEB-INF* view folder and suffix *.jsp*). You can have multiple error-page elements of other error codes too.

```
<error-page>
    <error-code>404</error-code>
    <location>/error</location>
</error-page>
```

If you are not using `web.xml` it's a bit more complicated.

If you want to catch the `NoHandlerFound` exception you first have to tell Spring to throw it via [setting a flag in the DispatcherServlet directly](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/DispatcherServlet.html#setThrowExceptionIfNoHandlerFound-boolean-).

To do so, in the class that you are extending `AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer` override the `onStartup` method to expose the DispatcherServlet definition and add manually the needed flag:

```
@Override
public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext) throws ServletException {

    //...
    WebApplicationContext context = getContext();
    DispatcherServlet dispatcherServlet = new DispatcherServlet(context);
    //we did all this to set the below flag
    dispatcherServlet.setThrowExceptionIfNoHandlerFound(true);
    ServletRegistration.Dynamic dispatcher = servletContext.addServlet("DispatcherServlet",dispatcherServlet );
    //..
}
```

Then your existing code within `ExceptionController` should work and intercept the exception

Comment: I am already settting throwExceptionIfNoHandlerFound true in the onStartup method and it works when I remove the "addResourceHandlers" method from WebConfig. I am not able to use both of them together.

Comment: It's probably because you have setup registry.addResourceHandler("/**") which includes everything. Judging from your resource location, can't you define registry.addResourceHandler("/static/**") to narrow the static content down?

Comment: :) That did it.
Thanks a lot.

Could you please let me know why it clashed?